# HTML Table Display from SQL Database

Tags: mysql, charts, google-visualization

Struggling with integrating Google (pie) charts with a MYSQL Database. It is trying to retrieve data from a database called 'mxp937_AddStakeholder' and in particular the column name is, 'ProjectRoles' that contains string data for example, Manager, Full Time Stakeholder, Software Developer .... GUI Designer. Eventually this data needs to be displayed into a pie chart and shows information for example, 5% of users are a Software Developer etc.

The error I get is: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.

Please advice?

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("Failed to connect with database!");
mysql_select_db("mxp937_AddStakeholder", $con); 
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT projectroles FROM mxp937_AddStakeholder");
$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

array('label' => 'Project Roles', 'type' => 'string'),

);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$temp = array();
// the following line will used to slice the Pie chart
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['ProjectRoles']); 

//Values of the each slice
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['percentage']); 
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;
?>

<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
  var options = {
       title: 'Project Roles',
      is3D: 'true',
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    };
  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  //do not forget to check ur div ID
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the name of your database ("mxp937_AddStakeholder")

```
mysql_select_db("mxp937_AddStakeholder", $con);
```

This should be the name of the table your selecting the results from

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echoing the error you get from the query execution? Because if your query doesn't run successfully (e.g. It has some syntax issues) then you won't have a result to manipulate. Try

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

after running the query.

Also, you should stop using mysql_* functions and start using mysqli_* ones, or you can use PDO. mysql_* functions are in the process of eing depricated.